# Проблемы с валидацией на Spring Boot + Oval

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Использую Spring Boot 1.3 и OVal 1.85.
Моя модель:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company extends BaseModel {

    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 5, max = 50)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "name", length = 50)
    private String name;

}
```

Мой контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Company saveCompany(@RequestBody(required = true) @Valid Company company) {
        return companyService.save(company);
    }
}
```

Но аннотация @Valid пропускает некорректные значения.
Проект без XML, только аннотации.
Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: А некоторые это какие? Вы уверенны что аннотации все из одной либы?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: собакаValid - javax.validation
собакаNotNull, собакаNotBlank, собакаLength - аннотации овала.
В интернете есть примеры, как подменить бины так, чтобы собакаValid работала с аннотациями овала, но только на XML, что мне не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если верить [примеру со spring.io](http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/), вам нужно самому проверять результаты валидации в методе контроллера:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Company saveCompany(@RequestBody(required = true) @Valid Company company, BindingResult bindingResult /*результаты валидации*/) {
        if ( bindingResult.hasErrors() ) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Company>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Company>( companyService.save(company), HttpStatus.OK );
    }
}
```

Параметр `BindingResult` должен следовать прямо за параметром, отмеченным `@Valid`. В результатах валидации будет то, что наработал используемый в Spring [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/). Аннотации для него выглядят следующим образом (полное имя приведено, чтоб было понятно, что должно быть в импорте):

```
@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank
@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length(min = 5, max = 50)
```

Если непременно нужен OVal, создайте в классе с `@SpringBootApplication` бин:

```
@Bean
public org.springframework.validation.Validator validator() {
    return new net.sf.oval.integration.spring.SpringValidator( new net.sf.oval.Validator() );
}
```

внедрите его в контроллер, и вызывайте руками:

```
@Autowired
private org.springframework.validation.Validator validator;

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Company> saveCompany(@RequestBody(required = true) Company company, BindingResult bindingResult /*результаты валидации*/) {
    validator.validate( company, bindingResult );
    /* ... */
}
```

Дополнительно:

В [этом посте](https://springarticles.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/mvc-validation/) задачу по уборке одинакового кода обработки ошибок валидации решили через AOP.

Comment: А вот в примере с бином, как то можно проверять не в ручную, а через аннотацию @valid ?